# Wrong convergence using optimize.fmin_l_bfgs_b

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization, scipy

I'm using optimize.fmin_l_bfgs_b to optimize a function written in Fortran. The code is something similar to:

```
def f(m, *args):
    # Optmization values
    Opt1 = m[0]
    Opt2 = m[1]
    # Rest of arguments:
    Var1 = args[0]
    Var2 = args[1]
    # Fortran Function
    r1, r2 = FortranFunction(Opt1, Opt2)
    # Evaluation of the result
    evaluation = sqrt((r1-Var1)**2 + (r2-Var2)**2)
    return evaluation

initial_values = numpy.array([1.09, 0.0025])
mybounds = [(1, 1.2), (0, 0.1)]
m = optimize.fmin_l_bfgs_b(f, x0 = initial_values, args=(x, file_vars), approx_grad = True, bounds = mybounds)
```

The fortran function returns 2 values that are used to evaluate the function using the two desired results (Var1 and Var2). The problem I have is that the algorithm doesn't optimize the first variable. If I print it in each iteration, this is what I obtain:

```
1.09
1.09
1.09000001
1.09
1.09
1.09
1.09000001
1.09
1.09
1.09
1.09000001
1.09
1.09
1.09
1.09000001
...
```

It seems it is only evaluating the function by the difference between 1.09 and 1.09000001, which is too low to obtain a different value in the Fortran function (which may be the reason for what it is not optimized). The second variable doesn't present this problem. Is this a normal behavior? Is there any option to make the algorithm use a higher step?

Comment: What does it do when you enter different starting values?

Comment: Exactly the same. The Fortran function is not very sensitive to such low variations on the first variable.

Comment: Have you looked at an approximation of the gradient of the optimized solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a broad range of possible fixes depending on what exactly the Fortran function does. I see from your call signature that you're having the minimizer estimate the gradient numerically. Can you calculate the gradient *directly*? If so, try writing a function that does that, pass it as `fprime`, and set `approx_grad` to `False`. There's a good chance that a proper gradient function will give better results.

Another possibility would be to try different values of `epsilon`, which controls the step size for numerical gradient approximation. But it looks to me like [`fmin_l_bfgs_b`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin_l_bfgs_b.html) only accepts a single floating point value for `epsilon`, which means that you can't adopt different step sizes for different dimensions. That might not be a problem; if a larger epsilon gives a better gradient estimate for the first dimension, and doesn't throw off estimates for the second dimension, then your problem may be fixed. You could also try passing an array, with an epsilon value for each dimension -- it *might* work. And finally, you might be able to do something a little bit clunky like optimize one dimension, then adjust epsilon, and then optimize the other dimension. I'll do some experimentation later if I have the time.

A final approach might be to use a different minimization function. Have you tried `fmin_cg`, for example? I've found that it handles most of the problems I throw at it pretty well. But I've never used it without a hard-coded gradient function before. You might also try other functions on [this list](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html#id1) -- especially ones like `Powell` and `Anneal` that are designed to work without using any gradient information.

Which, if any, of these approaches works will depend heavily on the specific nature of the function you're trying to minimize. You may have to do some experimentation!

Comment: Modifying the step size through the epsilon value has corrected the problem with the first dimension. However, as suggested in your detailed comments, I will experiment with other options. For sure I'll try with other minimization functions, but also develop a new gradient function. Not sure how it is done now. Thank you very much for this helpful answer.